# i accidentally disabled my ubuntu profile

Tags: user-profile

I was trying to upgrade my 2nd computer's hard drive, and in the process, I un-admin'd and disabled my account. I'm using the guest account right now. I've tried everything that ask ubuntu has to offer (or at least after 5 hours of searching, trying, and failing) i.e., creating a new account (didn't allow me to do it), usermod, passwd, anything involving sudo, hell, I can't even get into recovery mode with the left shift thing... I really want to get into my account. Please help me.

Comment: What exactly did you already tried?.

Comment: Have you tried login in text mode? When on graphic login screen, type Ctrl+alt+F1, then try to login.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding Users To Admin / Sudo Group Using Recovery Mode

First shutdown your computer, then 'restart whilst holding shift' on the keyboard to load grub menu.

Select 'recovery mode' from the grub menu.

Select 'drop to root shell' from the recovery menu.

Remount the drive with write permission using `mount -o rw,remount /`

Now type `adduser username sudo` replacing username with your user name  ie. 'adduser  phil sudo'

You should now see a message saying 'adding user' followed by 'done'.

Type `shutdown -r now` to restart the computer.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. I can't get into recovery mode. My problem isn't as much the sudo thing, it's that my account is deactivated, and the only way I can use the computer is the guest session. I need the admin password to reactivate my account, but the admin password is deactivated with my profile.

Comment: Ok, if you can't get to recovery mode, have a look at this guide & video on my website on adding your username to admin using a live disc - please note that you will need to add your username to sudo in Ubuntu 12.04, admin is for 11.10 and earlier. Let me know if it works so I can edit my answer to include the details. Also just to double check did you remove the password from the admin account? http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/deletedadmin.html

Comment: The problem is that I disabled my account, so I can't login, and I can't re-enable it, because it doesn't let me use the admin password, because the admin account has been disabled. What I really need to know is how to re-enale an account from the outside, w/o the admin password.

Comment: You will either have to use the live disc as suggested in the comment, or use recovery mode. I think Fernhill Linux Project understands the situation. From recovery mode you are in a sudo state so you can do anything. That's the easiest way to solve the problem. From the live CD you can get to the file system on your system and manipulate it.

Comment: I assume you are not using wubi. Is that right?